# How to use Elasticsearch 5.x with Nutch / How to index HTML webpages in Elasticsearch 5?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, nutch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I am using Apache Nutch to index webpages into Elasticsearch.
When I tried to upgrade like [this](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/indexer-elastic/howto_upgrade_es.txt), I am getting error in ElasticSearchWriter.java.
Have anyone attempted this?
Does Nutch support only till ES2.x?
Or Is there any other simple way to index HTML pages in ES?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished implementing this for Apache Nutch 2.3.1 to ElasticSearch 5.1.1. This should be able to be back ported to earlier versions. Let me know if you need a different version...

Try This:

https://github.com/mdigiacomi/indexer-elastic

Comment: For anyone else interested, this is the module -https://github.com/futureweb/indexer-elastic